# Looking for an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I have a very long "list" of numbers ( maybe thousands ) which may be grouped, by sum into "n" groups. The number of groups and values are given. For example:

- List of numbers: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
- Groups:[3, 15, 21]

I need to find a summary of which numbers in the "list" will crate given "groups".

- 3 = 1+2
- 15 = 5+10
- 21 = 6+7+8

We may assume numbers are integers but may be negative. It looks like a subset sum problem, but one of the biggest constraints is matching ALL the numbers to ALL groups.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: So your example is not actually a valid example (all integers)?

Comment: Do you know in advance if there is **always** a solution? Also, I don't think 8.5 is classed as an integer

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried the subset sum algorithm, but taking into consideration list size ( 1000s of numbers ) this solution is not feasible, takes too long... It's NP-complete. 
Regarding integers - I am dealing with floats, but assuming the solution maybe easier using ints I can multiply by 100 and roundup to int.

Comment: @JCaesar It is always a solution and I fixed my example.

Comment: @DoktopAibolit Sadly, "NP-complete" is not a qualifier for an algorithm. It's the subset sum **problem** itself which is NP-complete. And, in all generality, your problem is at least as hard as the subset sum problem. I say "in all generality". If you have any more information, any assumption on the numbers that you have, it might help.

Comment: You basically need to solve at least `len(groups)` subset sum problems having negative numbers. Which would be exponential given there are no constraints to numbers or group values.

Comment: You can express the problem as an ILP and use an ILP solver. The translation to ILP is very easy, but whether or not any specific problem will be solvable in practice you'll have to find out.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that your problem is at least as hard as subset sum very easily.

Recall that subset sum is "Given a set of integer of S, is there a subset s of S that sum to T".

If we frame this as your problem we would want two groups `T` and `sum(S)-T`. If you could solve your problem with these two groups, we would also have a solution two the original subset sum problem.  We  see that an algorithm that solves your problem also would solve Subset Sum, but since Subset Sum is a NP-complete problem, we can also say that your problem is NP-hard. (This is known as a reduction from a NP-hard problem).

To show that the problem is NP-complete we have to also show that problem is in NP. A problem in NP is any decision problem where a solution can be verified in polynomial time.  Given any proposed solution to your problem, it is trivial to verify if the sum in each group is what we want it to be. So the problem is also in NP.

As such there is (probably) no polynomial time algorithm solving your problem.  There might be pseudo-polynomial algorithms such as Knapsack that could work, but since you state your problem size is in the thousands there is no hope these will be fast enough.

Comment: You've not proved that the problem is NP complete, you've proved it's NP hard. To show it's NP complete, you'd also have to show a reduction from this problem into an NP complete problem. (Note that it's easy to represent the problem as an integer linear program, so it _is_ actually NP complete).

Comment: @Paul Hankin *"you'd also have to show a reduction from this problem into an NP complete problem"* - That's neither the definition nor the typical way to prove it, is it?

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't know about typical, but it's a common way. Here it's easy to prove the problem is NP directly from the definition (and NP-complete follows from NP + NP-hard) - perhaps that's what you are alluding to.

Comment: I was perhaps not careful enough in my comment. I was simply trying to point out that this answer did not prove NP-complete, merely NP-hard, and that there's an easy reduction to ILP which could complete the proof.

Comment: I have shown NP hardness, that the problem is in NP is trivial, so it is NP complete.

Comment: I updated my answer to show NP membership